# Bellman Ford algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Please review my code and help me to improve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <map>

class Graph
{
    int vertex_count;

    enum { INF = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

    struct Vertex
    {
        int id;
        int distance;
        Vertex * parent;

        Vertex(int _id) : id(std::move(_id)),
                          distance(INF),
                          parent(nullptr)
                          {}
    };
    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    //std::pair<int, int> edge;
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> edge_weight;

  public:
    Graph(int);
    void add_edge(int, int, int); //source, destination, weight
    bool bellman_ford(int); //source
    void distance_from_source();

  private:
    void initialize_single_source(int); //source
    void relax(int, int, int); //source, destination, weight
};

Graph::Graph(int v)
{
    vertex_count = v;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count; i++)
    {
        vertices.push_back(Vertex(i));
    }
}

void Graph::initialize_single_source(int src)
{
    vertices[src].distance = 0;
}

void Graph::add_edge(int src, int dest, int weight)
{
    edge_weight.insert(std::make_pair( std::make_pair(src, dest), weight ));
}

void Graph::relax(int src, int dest, int weight)
{
    auto wt =  edge_weight.find(std::make_pair(src, dest));
    if (vertices[dest].distance > (vertices[src].distance + wt->second))
    {
        vertices[dest].distance = (vertices[src].distance + wt->second);
        vertices[dest].parent = &vertices[src];
    }
}

bool Graph::bellman_ford(int src)
{
    initialize_single_source(src);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (auto it = edge_weight.begin(); it != edge_weight.end(); it++)
        {
            relax(it->first.first, it->first.second, it->second);
        }
    }

    for (auto it = edge_weight.begin(); it != edge_weight.end(); it++)
    {
        if (vertices[it->first.second].distance > (vertices[it->first.first].distance + it->second))
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Graph::distance_from_source()
{
    std::cout << "Vertex\t\tDistance from Source\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < vertex_count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vertices[i].id <<"\t\t" << vertices[i].distance <<"\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Graph grp(5);
    grp.add_edge(0, 1, 6);
    grp.add_edge(0, 2, 7);
    grp.add_edge(1, 3, 5);
    grp.add_edge(1, 4, -4);
    grp.add_edge(1, 2, 8);
    grp.add_edge(2, 3, -3);
    grp.add_edge(2, 4, 9);
    grp.add_edge(3, 1, -2);
    grp.add_edge(4, 0, 2);
    grp.add_edge(4, 3, 7);

    bool res = grp.bellman_ford(0);
    if (res == true)
       std::cout << "Graph contains no negative cycle \n";
    else
       std::cout << "Graph conatins negative cycle \n";

    grp.distance_from_source();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Vertex class

The `INF` constant is used only as the initializer for `Vertex::distance`, so I'd inline the value directly, like this:

```
struct Vertex
{
    const int id;
    int distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    Vertex *parent = nullptr;

    Vertex(int id)
        : id(id)
    {}
};
```

I've inlined the initializers that don't depend on arguments, and I've removed the `std::move` cast that has no benefit for a primitive type.  Since that constructor is now the same as default, we can omit it.

## Graph class

The `vertex_count` member can (and should) be declared `const`; that also requires it to be initialized (not assigned) in the constructor.  That said, there's no need for it, as we can always use `vertices.size()`.

The constructor argument isn't obvious from the class definition - name it and if necessary also add a comment.

Naming: `distance_from_source()` sounds like it can be used to obtain the results, but it actually prints to standard output.  I'd rename it to something like (using `#include <iosfwd>`):

```
std::ostream& print_distances(std::ostream&) const;
```

## Constructor

We should tell the vector its final size, so it can reserve capacity and avoid multiple allocations.

We can use `emplace_back()` to simplify the population of the vector:

```
Graph::Graph(int v)
    : vertex_count(v)
{
    vertices.reserve(vertex_count);
    for (int i = 0;  i < vertex_count;  ++i) {
        vertices.emplace_back(i);
    }
}
```

## Adding edges

The `add_edge` method doesn't check that `src` and `dest` are within range, and it does nothing if an edge already exists.  We can easily detect these conditions:

```
void Graph::add_edge(int src, int dest, int weight)
{
    if (src == dest) {
        throw std::logic_error("src==dest");
    }
    if (src < 0 || vertex_count <= src) {
        throw std::out_of_range("src");
    }
    if (dest < 0 || vertex_count <= dest) {
        throw std::out_of_range("dest");
    }

    auto const inserted = edge_weight.insert({ {src, dest}, weight });
    if (!inserted.second) {
        throw std::logic_error("existing edge");
    }
}
```

I recommend changing the index type from `int` to an unsigned type (e.g. `std::size_t`) as negative values are not valid.

Also, the use of `std::pair` rather than a specific structure makes it hard to follow code full of `first` and `second` all meaning different things.

## Relaxing weights

It's inefficient to have to re-`find()` an edge.  However, we're passing `weight` to avoid that, so just re-use it:

```
void Graph::relax(int src, int dest, int weight)
{
    auto & existing = vertices[dest].distance;
    auto const proposed = vertices[src].distance + weight;
    if (proposed < existing) {
        existing = proposed;
    }
}
```

I've dropped the update to `parent` since we never use it.

## Bellman-Ford computation

If we want to recalculate with a different origin node, we'll need to reset initial distances to maximum, as well as setting the origin to zero.

---

## Modified program

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class Graph
{
    using index_type = std::size_t;
    using distance_type = int;

    static const distance_type max_distance;

    struct Vertex
    {
        const index_type id;
        distance_type distance = max_distance;
    };

    struct Edge
    {
        index_type from;
        index_type to;
        bool operator<(const Edge& other) const
        {
            return std::tie(from, to) < std::tie(other.from, other.to);
        }
    };

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices = {};
    std::map<Edge,distance_type> edge_weight = {};

public:
    Graph(index_type size);
    void add_edge(index_type from, index_type to, distance_type weight);
    bool bellman_ford(index_type origin); // true if no negative cycles
    std::ostream& print_distances(std::ostream&) const;

private:
    void relax(index_type from, index_type to, distance_type weight);
};
```

```
// Implementation

#include <limits>
#include <ostream>

const Graph::distance_type Graph::max_distance
    = std::numeric_limits<distance_type>::max();

Graph::Graph(index_type size)
{
    vertices.reserve(size);
    for (index_type i = 0;  i < size;  ++i) {
        vertices.push_back(Vertex{i});
    }
}

void Graph::add_edge(index_type src, index_type dest, distance_type weight)
{
    if (src == dest) {
        throw std::logic_error("src==dest");
    }
    if (vertices.size() <= src) {
        throw std::out_of_range("src");
    }
    if (vertices.size() <= dest) {
        throw std::out_of_range("dest");
    }

    auto const inserted = edge_weight.insert({ Edge{src, dest}, weight });
    if (!inserted.second) {
        throw std::logic_error("existing edge");
    }
}

void Graph::relax(index_type src, index_type dest, distance_type weight)
{
    auto& existing = vertices[dest].distance;
    auto const proposed = vertices[src].distance + weight;
    if (proposed < existing) {
        existing = proposed;
    }
}

bool Graph::bellman_ford(index_type src)
{
    // initialise distances
    for (auto& vertex: vertices) {
        vertex.distance = max_distance;
    }
    vertices[src].distance = 0;

    // relax edges
    for (index_type i = 1;  i < vertices.size();  ++i) {
        for (auto edge: edge_weight) {
            relax(edge.first.from, edge.first.to, edge.second);
        }
    }

    // check for negative-weight cycles
    for (auto edge: edge_weight) {
        auto const& from_vertex = vertices[edge.first.from];
        auto const& to_vertex = vertices[edge.first.to];
        if (to_vertex.distance > from_vertex.distance + edge.second) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // success!
    return true;
}

std::ostream& Graph::print_distances(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << "Vertex\t\tDistance from Source\n";
    for (auto vertex: vertices) {
        os << vertex.id << "\t\t" << vertex.distance << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

```
// Test program

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Graph grp(5);
    grp.add_edge(0, 1, 6);
    grp.add_edge(0, 2, 7);
    grp.add_edge(1, 3, 5);
    grp.add_edge(1, 4, -4);
    grp.add_edge(1, 2, 8);
    grp.add_edge(2, 3, -3);
    grp.add_edge(2, 4, 9);
    grp.add_edge(3, 1, -2);
    grp.add_edge(4, 0, 2);
    grp.add_edge(4, 3, 7);

    if (grp.bellman_ford(0))
        std::cout << "Graph contains no negative cycle \n";
    else
        std::cout << "Graph conatins negative cycle \n";

    grp.print_distances(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: I'm all for useful type aliases, but is replacing int with one really necessary and/or wise in this case? And the standard library uses size_t already for indices, so why do we need to rename it index_type?

Comment: Perhaps not so useful for `index_type`, where `std::size_t` could certainly be used throughout, but the `distance_type` could save a lot of pain if you later want to use `long` or `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Why we have overloaded operator `<` in `struct Edge {...}` ?

Comment: You need an `operator<` for anything you want to use as a key in `std::map`.  BTW, it's not overloaded at all; just defined.

Answer (score 5):

By not using `using namespace std` you're already ahead of the curve, well done.

- Why is part of your class outside of your private/public scope? In this case it will be private by default so you should move it to avoid confusion.
- Use compiler warnings. You have an unused parameter (weight) in your *relax* function. Turning on `-Weffc++` will bring up another valid point. You're using a member initializer list for your *Vertex* struct so why not use it for your Graph class as well?
- Why are you omitting parameter names and then adding them as comments? Just add parameter names to your class interface and get rid of the comments instead.
- Why do you have a single line function (`initialize_single_source`) that is called only once?
- I don't know which compiler/standard you're using but if possible you should consider using some of the new features (scoped enums, smart pointers, range based for loops).

Comment: `std::move()` implies at least C++11, where all those features are available.  (The `move` is unnecessary and unhelpful for a plain `int`, but it's there)

Comment: @TobySpeight good catch, all the more reason to ask why they are not utilized.

Comment: @TobySpeight how do I know when to use `std::move` ?

Comment: Good question.  It wasn't doing any *harm* where it was, other than adding clutter, which slows understanding.  A good rule is to use it when your initializer needs a *copy* of an object that *manages some sort of resource* (e.g. a smart pointer, or a collection).